# When I press Enter anywhere on a web page, why does my fixed positioned Overlay layer disappear?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a normal page with a login button. On clicking the login button, I use jQuery to bring up a hidden overlay layer, which contains a login form. The overlay layer is fixed positioned. When I press Enter no matter what is focused or where is mouse cursor s the the moment, the overlay layer is gone, revealing the normal page. So what is happening here? Does it have to do which form dfault button or something? But I do not seem to see any change in my normal page except the overlay is gone.

Comment: Is there a cancel button in your login overlay? It could be defaulted to that as the button to click when you hit enter. It is kind of hard to tell without knowing what your overlay looks like.

Comment: My guess is that by pressing ENTER the page gets reloaded and thereby returned to its initial state. Do you submit the login via Ajax?

Comment: @Šime Vidas: Hi that was what happened! Is that a reload or a postback? Why did that happen? Because of the default button? What do I do to remove any default button? Thanks.

Comment: you need to focus on the button using onFocus listener else it will be reloading everytime you press enter

Comment: @Aperture It's a submit I believe. The login form gets submitted. Why do you want to prevent this behavior? It is expected that the user will first fill in the login information, and then press ENTER to submit the form.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas It looks to me like the original question has been answered. If so, might I suggest adding it as an answer so the OP can mark it as the solution?